# How do I use next-auth within a nextjs component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-component, next-auth

I'm trying too split my application into multiple components, and I'm trying to create a dashboard component, however, how do I go about implementing next-auth within the component, previously I had `getServerSideProps` but as this is a component I can't do that.

Here is my component

```
import {
  SearchIcon,
  BellIcon,
  UserCircleIcon,
  ChevronDownIcon,
  UserIcon,
  LogoutIcon
} from '@heroicons/react/outline';

import { signOut } from 'next-auth/client';

export default function Navigation(...session) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="py-6 px-8 lg:h-16 lg:flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-700 text-white">
        <div className="flex-1">
          <div className="lg:pr-4 lg:py-4">
            <label htmlFor="search" className="sr-only">
              Search
            </label>

            <div className="relative">
              <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center">
                <SearchIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-white" aria-hidden="true" />
              </div>

              <input
                id="search"
                name="search"
                className="block w-full bg-blue-800 border border-blue-800 rounded-md py-2 pl-10 pr-3 text-sm placeholder-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-white focus:border-white sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Search"
                type="search"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="relative flex items-center justify-center mt-8 lg:mt-0">
          <div className="relative mr-6">
            <BellIcon className="w-5" />

            <small className="text-xs absolute -top-1 -right-2 -mt-2 bg-red-500 rounded-full py-0.5 px-1.5">
              1
            </small>
          </div>

          <details className="relative">
            <summary className="flex items-center">
              <UserCircleIcon className="w-5 mr-2" />

              <h2>
                {session.user.firstname} {session.user.lastname}
              </h2>

              <ChevronDownIcon
                className="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 h-4 w-4 text-blue-200"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </summary>

            <div className="w-full mt-4 pb-4 absolute shadow-lg flex flex-col justify-center px-2 space-y-1 bg-blue-700">
              <Link href="/dashboard/myprofile">
                <a className="bg-blue-800 text-white hover:bg-blue-600 flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md">
                  <UserIcon className="w-5 h-5 mr-2" />
                  Profile
                </a>
              </Link>

              <Link href="#">
                <a
                  onClick={signOut}
                  className="bg-blue-800 text-white hover:bg-blue-600 flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md">
                  <LogoutIcon className="w-5 h-5 mr-2" />
                  Sign out
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </details>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Currently what I'm getting is the following

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstname')
```

**edit #1**

Here is my `_app.js` [UPDATED]

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Provider } from 'next-auth/client';

// assets
import '../styles/global.css';
import '../javascripts/app.js';

// components
import Footer from './components/Footer';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#1E40AF" />
      </Head>

      <section className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
        <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
          <Component {...pageProps} className="flex-1" />
        </Provider>
      </section>

      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`useSession`](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession) in your component?

Comment: @juliomalves I've tried it but I couldn't get the session to pass

Comment: Are you not using a [`SessionProvider`](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#sessionprovider) in your `_app` file?

Comment: @juliomalves I've added my app.js file as an edit.

Comment: If you're not passing the session anywhere from SSR, you probably need to use [`getSession()`​](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession) inside a `useEffect` to retrieve it.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an example @juliomalves, I'm new to react, sorry.

Comment: @juliomalves I've updated the _app.js file but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I did the following

`_app.js` - Now using provider to share the session across all pages.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Provider } from 'next-auth/client';

// assets
import '../styles/global.css';
import '../javascripts/app.js';

// components
import Footer from './components/Footer';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#1E40AF" />
      </Head>

      <section className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
        <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
          <Component {...pageProps} className="flex-1" />
        </Provider>
      </section>

      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

and for the component I now have the following

```
import {
  SearchIcon,
  BellIcon,
  UserCircleIcon,
  ChevronDownIcon,
  UserIcon,
  LogoutIcon
} from '@heroicons/react/outline';

import { useSession, signOut } from 'next-auth/client';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Navigation() {
  const [session, loading] = useSession()

  return (
    <>
      <div className="py-6 px-8 lg:h-16 lg:flex justify-between items-center bg-blue-700 text-white">
        <div className="flex-1">
          <div className="lg:pr-4 lg:py-4">
            <label htmlFor="search" className="sr-only">
              Search
            </label>

            <div className="relative">
              <div className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center">
                <SearchIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-white" aria-hidden="true" />
              </div>

              <input
                id="search"
                name="search"
                className="block w-full bg-blue-800 border border-blue-800 rounded-md py-2 pl-10 pr-3 text-sm placeholder-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-white focus:border-white sm:text-sm"
                placeholder="Search"
                type="search"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="relative flex items-center justify-center mt-8 lg:mt-0">
          <div className="relative mr-6">
            <BellIcon className="w-5" />

            <small className="text-xs absolute -top-1 -right-2 -mt-2 bg-red-500 rounded-full py-0.5 px-1.5">
              1
            </small>
          </div>

          <details className="relative">
            <summary className="flex items-center">
              <UserCircleIcon className="w-5 mr-2" />

              { session &&
                <h2>
                  {session.firstname} { session.lastname}
                </h2>
              }

              <ChevronDownIcon
                className="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 h-4 w-4 text-blue-200"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </summary>

            <div className="w-full mt-4 pb-4 absolute shadow-lg flex flex-col justify-center px-2 space-y-1 bg-blue-700">
              <Link href="/dashboard/myprofile">
                <a className="bg-blue-800 text-white hover:bg-blue-600 flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md">
                  <UserIcon className="w-5 h-5 mr-2" />
                  Profile
                </a>
              </Link>

              <Link href="#">
                <a
                  onClick={signOut}
                  className="bg-blue-800 text-white hover:bg-blue-600 flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md">
                  <LogoutIcon className="w-5 h-5 mr-2" />
                  Sign out
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </details>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```